# how to apply logging in spring boot in external log file?

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot, log4j

I am trying to apply logging in external file in my spring boot project. Is it possible. I have followed many websites. Please help.

Comment: i am not able to create log file. Its printing on console only.

Answer (score 2):

You have to define a `logback.xml` file at the root of the classpath (typically in `src/main/resources`).

**Example :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/base.xml" />

    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
        <file>logs.log</file>
        <append>true</append>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%-4relative [%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg%n
            </pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>


    <logger name="org.springframework.web" level="DEBUG" />
    <logger name="your.custom.package" level="TRACE" />

    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

This configuration creates a `logs.log` file (at the root of your Maven project).

Check the [Spring](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-logging.html#howto-configure-logback-for-logging) and [Logback](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html) documentations to get more details.

Answer (score 1):

Just add this line to your application.yaml (or equivalent in application.properties)

```
logging:
  file: directorname/nameoflogfile.log
```

Spring Boot will handle the rest. I don't think you explicitly need to add in a logback.xml as there's one shipped in the classpath anyway.