# Spring boot using slf4j no log file created

Tags: java, spring-boot, slf4j

I have a spring boot application with trying to use slf4j by following tutorial from https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-logging however logs are getting printed only on console side. There is no log file created in given directory `/var/logs`.

**log4j2-spring.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration>
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout
                    pattern="%style{%d{ISO8601}}{black} %highlight{%-5level }[%style{%t}{bright,blue}] %style{%C{1.}}{bright,yellow}: %msg%n%throwable" />
        </Console>

        <RollingFile name="RollingFile"
                     fileName="/var/logs/spring-boot-logger-log4j2.log"
                     filePattern="/var/logs/$${date:yyyy-MM}/spring-boot-logger-log4j2-%d{-dd-MMMM-yyyy}-%i.log.gz">
            <PatternLayout>
                <pattern>%d %p %C{1.} [%t] %m%n</pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <!-- rollover on startup, daily and when the file reaches
                    10 MegaBytes -->
                <OnStartupTriggeringPolicy />
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
                        size="10 MB" />
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
            </Policies>
        </RollingFile>
    </Appenders>

    <Loggers>
        <!-- LOG everything at INFO level -->
        <Root level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console" />
            <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile" />
        </Root>

        <Logger name="com.buraktas">
            <AppenderRef ref="LogFile"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
        </Logger>
    </Loggers>

</Configuration>
```

maven dependencies

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: You can check this post, it's useful : https://stackoverflow.com/a/45051211/4373948

Comment: yup I tried those examples as well no luck. On the other hand, in that example they are using logback where I am trying to use slf4j

Comment: Ok and where you place your log4j2-spring.xml?

Comment: it is under `resources` directory.

Comment: Is it correct that you use `LogFile` for the `com.buraktas` logger and `RollingFile` for the root logger?

Comment: yeah kinda. I mean I was testing them by playing around. But I don't think that would be the problem right? Because there are no any log files created at all

Comment: Here is an example about using `appenders` under `Logger` property. https://github.com/fulloption55/thyme-spring-boot/blob/eae54fe1747b83b6bfeb6dc0d76cd100030538d9/src/main/resources/log4j2.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem where I had `spring-boot-starter` and `spring-boot-starter-web` dependencies. I excluded `spring-boot-starter-logging` dependency from only one of them which forced spring to use logback logger. And since logback logger doesn't pick up `log4j2.xml` for its configuration no files we getting created. So the pom.xml file was something like this;

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-web -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

I needed to exclude `spring-boot-starter-logging` from `spring-boot-starter` dependency as well. Well, after all since I have `spring-boot-starter-web` I just deleted `spring-boot-starter` package which was needless.

Answer (score 2):

You can define log path in the `application.properties` file, check the link below for example:

```
logging.level.com.example.springscheduler = debug
logging.level.org.springframework.web = WARN
logging.file.name =log/loggingdemocontroller.log
```

https://springbootmvc.blogspot.com/2020/06/spring-boot-logging-using-orgslf4jlogger.html